# mySQL INNER JOIN and Conditions

Tags: mysql, join, where, wordpress

I wrote a mySQL query that is just works as I need.

```
SELECT COUNT(wp_posts.ID) as count, wp_terms.term_id
FROM wp_terms 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag"
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish" 
GROUP BY wp_terms.term_id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

As you can see that, I have conditions when I'm joining to tables to eachother.

But I really, what is changes if I also add a `WHERE` statement to the end?

Like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(wp_posts.ID) as count, wp_terms.name
FROM wp_terms 
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag"
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id 
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id AND wp_posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish"
WHERE wp_posts.post_date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR) AND wp_posts.post_status = "publish" AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = "post_tag" 
GROUP BY wp_terms.term_id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

They both gives me the same results.

I really wonder, what is the diffirince?

Comment: You use INNER JOIN - so moving the condition from ON to WHERE changes nothing. The execution plan must be the same always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two queries do not give the same results -- one fetches `term_id`, one fetches `name`.  (I'll assume that was just a typo...)

The second query unnecessarily repeats the tests on `post_date` and `post_status`.  Remove from the `ON` because...

`ON` tells how two tables are "related".  `WHERE` filters the results.  For `INNER JOIN` there is no *functional* difference between them.  But it helps reading the query to put the tests in one place or the other.

`SELECT` syntax has a strict order:

```
SELECT
expression(s) to fetch
FROM
JOIN(s) with ON
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
ORDER BY
LIMIT (and OFFSET)
```

If you got the "same" results, then maybe all the taxonomy values are "post_tag"?

You cannot have two `WHERE` clauses, if that is what you are asking.

Add this plugin:  [*WP Index Improvements*](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Or, these indexes may help with speed:

```
wp_terms:  INDEX(term_id,  name)
wp_posts:  INDEX(post_status, post_date, ID)
wp_term_taxonomy:  INDEX(taxonomy, term_id)
wp_term_relationships:  INDEX(term_taxonomy_id,  object_id)
```